# Semaphore won't make the process sleep

Tags: c, linux, ipc, semaphore

i've got a problem with following code:

```
#include "updaterankparams.hpp"

int main()
{
sem_id = semget(SEM_KEY, 1, 0);

while(true)
{
    printf("want to lower: %d\n", semctl(sem_id, 0, GETVAL));
    semop(sem_id, &P, 1);
    printf("lowered: %d\n", semctl(sem_id, 0, GETVAL));
    scanf("%*c");
    puts("t");
    semop(sem_id, &V, 1);
}
return 0;
}
```

Where

```
static sembuf P =
{
  0,
  -1,
  0
};

static sembuf V =
{
  0,
  1,
  0
};
```

And the output i get is:

```
done
want to lower: 0
lowered: 0

t
want to lower: 1
lowered: 0

t
want to lower: 1
lowered: 0
```

and it goes on and on in infinity as i enter the chars in order to satisfy the printf in the loop.
But i want the process to stop (sleep) when it tries to lower a semaphore that's value is already zero. Though, nothing of the kind happens! I know it's probably a silly thing to ask and the solution is trivial, but it's one of these mistakes that are so stupid, nobody even asks for the solution online, I would imagine.

Just to clearify: none other process uses the semaphore and it has been initialized in other(now closed) process using:

```
sem_id = semget(SEM_KEY, 1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
```

thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Could you please post enough code so we can run it and observe your problem ?

Comment: You are doing P and V in the loop, the P always being at value 1. Where exactly should it stop and why?

Comment: if you want to run, it, just add the line with semget to the code and define SEM_KEY with some integer, e.g. 2000000001

Answer (score 1):

*TL;DR:* You have to create the semaphore with `semget`, then give it a "value" with `semop`, the default being 0 ( neat :) ).

From what I get, your P and V `sembuf`s are Locking and Unlocking respectively, by 1 ressource.

**EDIT:** Your semaphore has a value of 0 at the start because you haven't initialized it. have a look at the example [given here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/semget.html) namely:

```
/* Semaphore does not exist - Create. */
if ((semid = semget(semkey, 1, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | S_IRUSR |
    S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH)) != -1)
{
    /* Initialize the semaphore. <- v THIS IS IMPORTANT v */
    sbuf.sem_num = 0;
    sbuf.sem_op = 2;  /* This is the number of runs
                         without queuing. <- THIS IS WHERE YOU SET IT TO 1 */
    sbuf.sem_flg = 0;
    if (semop(semid, &sbuf, 1) == -1) {
        perror("IPC error: semop"); exit(1);
    }
}
```

I think you mixed the number of semaphores, and the number of available ressources in the same semaphore, I did. `semget` creates 1 semaphore, but you have to set it to 1 ressource available, with a call to `semop`. One semaphore can be used with more than one available ressource (see the train example below).

In your `while` loop, you first *lock* the semaphore, with the line `semop(sem_id, &P, 1);` then you *unlock* it immediately with the line `semop(sem_id, &V, 1);`.

This being in your `main`, I guess you have no other thread running, so no concurrent access to your ressources and thus semaphores. Your program will never have to wait because the semaphore is locked, you enter a char, the semaphore is unlocked then locked again at the next loop go-through. The value of your semaphore is never 0 when you try to lock it, as it has been released just before.

Have a look at threading if you want to try-out your semaphores and get a waiting time. A nice exercise would be to try and make 3 trains cross only 1 bridge, and have a little display like so, for example:

```
[][][][]>--------________---------
[][][][]>--------        ---------
[][][][]>--------        ---------
```

Your ressource-limit is the bridge (only one here) and you have one thread per train, doing the same thing, like:

```
//Init the semaphore with 1 ressource available (the one bridge)
semop(sem_id, &V, 1);

//Threaded code :
while (position != trackSize)
{
  if ((position < (bridgePosition - 1))  //Before the bridge
      || (position > bridgeEnd))   //After the bridge
  {
    position++;
  }
  else //On the bridge
  {
    if (semop(sem_id, &P, 1) != -1) //Lock the bridge for this train
                                    // will wait if the bridge is already in use
    {
      while (position < bridgeEnd) position++; //Go through the bridge at once
    }
    semop(sem_id, &V, 1); //Unlock the bridge, let other trains use it
  }
}
```

If you had 2 bridges, you would still have 1 semaphore/sem_id, but you would set it to 2 available ressources, so two trains could "lock" the same semaphore at the same time.

I hope this helps you understand why you have no waiting in your program's execution.

Comment: I realize that the program should be running without waiting bacause of locking and unlocking having place in almost the same time, but what bothers me is that i print the value of the semaphore BEFORE locking it and the first time the program locks this value is 0, but every next time it is 1. Then, if the semaphore value is 0 BEFORE the locking (first semaphore usage), how can the program even lock it and continue going on?

Comment: From your output, I see `want to lower: 1`, so I don't know where you see the value is 0 before locking it? EDIT: ah you mean only the first time, sorry

Comment: Where does the `done` output come from? Have you got any other code running between `semget` and the first loop ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I tried to simplify the code as much as possible before posting it, thus i deleted the line printing     done just before the loop. Sorry for the mess, but recompling without this print gives the same effect (except from printing    done , of course :))

Comment: Do you think it might be the output streaming problem (e.g. the value of the semaphore is being read in some other moment of program running)? Because it seems to be working fine, just the outputs are bothering me...

Comment: I don't think so, printf buffers the output but the value is read when calling printf, not when printf flushes its output. On top of that, printf flushes when the buffer has a newline, or you can force it using `fflush(0);`

Comment: @FilipKowalski Ok I've got it. I've edited my answer so you can see why it's doing this.